# Проблема с деплоем на HEROKU

Tags: git, heroku

Здравствуйте. Как человек начинающий свой путь, руководствовался материалами http://installfest.railsbridge.org/ . Следовал четко, но столкнулся с проблеой на этапе деплоя на хероку. После ввода:

> git push heroku master

Получаю:

> remote: !       WARNING:
>   remote: !       Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
>   remote: !       Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry
>   the git command.

хероку логин выполняется нормально, заходит). Нагуглил проблемы с расположением файла _netrc. но решения изложенные там не привели к нужному результату.

Comment: Вероятно, предлагает логиниться в git через SSH.

Answer (score 1):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#introduction

```
 heroku login
```

Нужно залогиниться на Heroku и, возможно, вы пропускаете этап создания сайта под ваш деплойный проект на самом Heroku через команду `heroku create`